# How to create this kind of GPUImage filter? Any idea?

Tags: objective-c, image-processing, gpuimage

I am learning to create some custom GPUImage filters. 
I am wondering how to do the following 2 filters. 
I am following the GPUImageFilter FilterShowcase project.
But all of those distortion filters are circle. 
The follow 2 are linear and I could see any example codes or GPUImageFilters from the Filtershowcase project. https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage
Does anyone have any idea how to do such effect?
Thanks!
[image] 
[image]

Comment: notice that these two filters only affect the middle part of the image and it's not a circle. And I really couldn't find out any such GPUImageFilters from the FilterShowCase project https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Comment: have you find any solution for these filters?